# C# cannot see C++ constructor that takes arguments

Tags: c#, c++, cross-language

I have a class created in C#, and I want to reference a C++ class that was created. When I try to create an instance of the C++ class in C#, it can see the default constructor, but it can't see the constructor with arguments.

C++ cppClass code:

```
cppClass:: cppClass(const char* charArray)
```

C# code:

```
cppClass temp = new cppClass(); // <-- This works.
cppClass temp = new cppClass("Take 2"); // <-- This does not work.
```

When I use the second code, I get `cppClass does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument`.

I've set up the reference from the C# project to the C++, it can see the structs and the default constructor, but it can't see the one with arguments. Do I need to write a wrapper to be able to pass arguments?

Comment: What are the arguments of your C++ struct constructor? You wouldn't be able to pass `std::string` references from C#, for instance.

Comment: @zneak I added in the constructor code.

Comment: @mydogisbox Not that I know of, the code is part of an old program that I am trying to port into C#, without having to re-write all the code.

Comment: @Bob : I think his point is that you can port it to _.NET_ without rewriting all the code, by way of C++/CLI. Why is C# specifically necessary?

Comment: You cannot use C++ classes in C#, simple as that. If the first line compiles in C# then either you have defined that class elsewhere in C# code or you are using C++/CLI.

Comment: Is the constructor `public`?  class members (unlike struct members) are `private` by default.

Comment: @Konrad : It's impractical, but _technically_ it's possible by way of `#pragma make_public` and P/Invoke specifying mangled names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your actual code then the constructor is `private` by default.  Check the header to make sure the constructor is in a `public` section:

```
public: 
   cppClass::cppClass(const char*)
```

Comment: Modified to proper c++ syntax.

Comment: Okay, I did that, but it still doesn't show up and I still get the same error. In Visual Studio 2010, I can see the constructor exists and public, and that the variables inside are private, but the metadata file created is declaring it as a struct without anything in it.

Comment: try changing the `const char*` to `System::String^` (managed pointer to a string).  You'll need to marshal the string if you want to use it as a char* but it's not terrible.  There's a basic overview of marshalling on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's what I'm going to do for now, no point re-writing the code (at this moment).